# Differentiating between a PIL and CV2 image

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am looking to use a TF model, but the image preprocessing requires PIL images. I want my program to be able to accept both PIL and CV2 images. I know how to convert a CV2 image to a PIL image, but I don't know how to differentiate between them to know when to apply the conversion.
So I need a condition like :

```
if image is PIL.Image:
    ...
elif image is CV2.Image:
   conversion
   ...
```

Does anyone have a method for this?

Comment: "type(...)" returns the type (class) object of the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open an image using `CV2` then it returns object of the type `numpy.ndarray` but PIL's `Image.open()` returns `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile`. So using that, you can basically differentiate which is used in your case (assuming there is no conversion or further processing involved which converted one image type to another).

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PIL import JpegImagePlugin

imgcv = cv2.imread('./koala.jpg')
print(type(imgcv))

imgpil = Image.open('./koala.jpg')
print(type(imgpil))

img = imgpil
if isinstance(img,JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile):
    print('PIL Image')
else:
    print('Not PIL')
```

##### Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
PIL Image
```

As mentioned in the comment of this answer (by Mark Setchell) that instead of changing the PIL's `JpegImageFile` class, we can also check `ndarray` check and then decide - since PIL's class might change in future or they may simply use different type. The check would be exactly the same though.

```
img = imgcv
if isinstance(img,numpy.ndarray):
    print('CV Image')
else:
    print('PIL Image')
```

Comment: Yes. Testing for `numpy.ndarray` or not is the better test as PIL may use a different type for different plugins/formats.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to differentiate. Just convert the image object immediately after reading it so that your program is always dealing with a consistent image type.